# Rows To Columns in SQL SERVER USING PIVOT Command (Replacing NULL Values To 0 & Display SUM Of ALL VALUES)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display rows to columns in Sql Server. I have seen the other questions but those columns are hardcoded in the pivot  but my columns will be dynamic.  What I have achieved till now. As shown in the screenshot I am able to convert the rows into columns but few things I am not able to accomplish.. Need your guyz help

1. Replacing NULL To 0 in All the Columns
2. Need to Add 1 more column which will show the sum of all Columns except the companyID

My SQL code:

```
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Convert VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @Columns = STUFF((
           SELECT '],[' + ErrClassfn
             from ArchimedesTables.dbo.PM_ErrClassificationSetup
            WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ISNULL(EndDate, GETDATE()), 101) 
                          Between CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
                          AND     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
            ORDER BY '],[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ID) ASC
              FOR
                  XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

SET @Convert = 'SELECT  * INTO #mynewTable FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(WQ.ErrClassfnID) as ErrorCount, UPPER(WQ.CompanyID) as CompanyID, 
           PME.ErrClassfn as ErrorName
      FROM Version25.dbo.WF_Quality AS WQ
      LEFT JOIN ArchimedesTables.dbo.PM_ErrClassificationSetup as PME
           ON WQ.ErrClassfnID = PME.ID
     GROUP BY
          UPPER(CompanyID), ErrClassfn
) Quality PIVOT ( SUM(ErrorCount)  For ErrorName IN (' + @Columns
    + ')) as PivotTable  SeLeCt * FROM #mynewTable'

EXEC(@Convert)
```

[image]

Comment: After Bluefeet's answer I've deleted the one I was working on. To supplement his answer - you might add total to @convert by putting this `SUM(COUNT(WQ.ErrClassfnID)) OVER (PARTITION BY UPPER(CompanyID)) AS Total` before from and adding "total" to the end of select list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the columns names, etc for a Dynamic Pivot, similar to this:

```
DECLARE @ColumnsNull VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Convert VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @ColumnsNull = STUFF((SELECT ', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(ErrClassfn) +', 0) as ['+ rtrim(ErrClassfn)+']' 
                   from ArchimedesTables.dbo.PM_ErrClassificationSetup
                   WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ISNULL(EndDate, GETDATE()), 101) 
                                  Between CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
                                  AND     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
                   ORDER BY ID ASC
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT  @Columns = STUFF((
           SELECT '],[' + ErrClassfn
             from ArchimedesTables.dbo.PM_ErrClassificationSetup
            WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ISNULL(EndDate, GETDATE()), 101) 
                          Between CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
                          AND     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
            ORDER BY '],[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ID) ASC
              FOR
                  XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 2, '') + ']'


SET @Convert = 'SELECT  CompanyID, '+ @ColumnsNull + '
                INTO #mynewTable 
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(WQ.ErrClassfnID) as ErrorCount, UPPER(WQ.CompanyID) as CompanyID, 
                           PME.ErrClassfn as ErrorName
                      FROM Version25.dbo.WF_Quality AS WQ
                      LEFT JOIN ArchimedesTables.dbo.PM_ErrClassificationSetup as PME
                           ON WQ.ErrClassfnID = PME.ID
                     GROUP BY
                          UPPER(CompanyID), ErrClassfn
                ) Quality PIVOT ( SUM(ErrorCount)  For ErrorName IN (' + @Columns
                    + ')) as PivotTable  SeLeCt * FROM #mynewTable'

EXEC(@Convert)
```

I would advise to write the query and get the columns working first, then add the data to a #temp table.  It will be easier to debug that way.

You can also create a `SUM()` field the same way, where you build it dynamically and then add it at in the final `SELECT`:

So it could be something like this that you could add to the final `SELECT`:

```
SELECT  @ColumnsTotal = STUFF((SELECT '+' + QUOTENAME(ErrClassfn) 
                   from ArchimedesTables.dbo.PM_ErrClassificationSetup
                   WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ISNULL(EndDate, GETDATE()), 101) 
                                  Between CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
                                  AND     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
                   ORDER BY ID ASC
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: Thanks BlueFeet... :) Your Sql Knowledge Rocks :)